# Android: How do I add a translucent geofence over the map

Tags: android, android-maps, android-geofence

Android: How do I add a translucent geofence over a map. I.e., i can fill it with a color but the map below is still visible.

[This is what I wish to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTOZx.png)

Comment: Welcom to StackOverFlow , edit your question

Comment: do you have a screenshot of what you are trying to implement?

Comment: I have added the image in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Color.argb()`.  To learn more, go to the Color class reference page (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).  Here is an example of making the blue translucent fill:

```
Color.argb(
    100, //This is your alpha.  Adjust this to make it more or less translucent
    Color.red(Color.BLUE), //Red component.
    Color.green(Color.BLUE),  //Green component.
    Color.blue(Color.BLUE));  //Blue component.
```

This will make the blue translucent color you wanted.  If you have a custom hex color (`0xFFFFFFFF`), just adjust the first byte (`0xFF......`) to make it more or less translucent.

**EDIT**

Here is a simple function that you can use to pass in the alpha and color to adjust it:

```
int alphaAdjust(int alpha, int color) {
    return Color.argb(
            alpha, //This is your alpha.  Adjust this to make it more or less translucent
            Color.red(color), //Red component.
            Color.green(color),  //Green component.
            Color.blue(color));  //Blue component.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Circle, it is very easy:
Having your geofence details already in place (geofLocation and geofRadius) you can do:

```
// Instantiates a new CircleOptions object and defines the center and radius
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
.strokeColor(Color.BLACK) //Outer black border
.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) //inside of the geofence will be transparent, change to whatever color you prefer like 0x88ff0000 for mid-transparent red
    .center(geofLocation) // the LatLng Object of your geofence location
    .radius(geofRadius)); // The radius (in meters) of your geofence

// Get back the mutable Circle
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

Comment: I can add a circle but I want the circle to be translucent. This will just give me a circumference and no paint inside the circle.

Comment: So replace fill color value with a non trasparent one

Answer (score 0):

Try the examples listed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes). I'd suggest to use a translucent circle to indicate your geofence.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
LatLng latLng = ...
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
circleOptions.center(latLng)
             .fillColor(Color.argb(64, 0, 255, 0))
             .strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
             .strokeWidth(1)
             .radius(100);
```

Notice the first argument in Color.argb() method (value 64), that argument controls the alpha/transculency of the circle, in this case it will be a transculent green circle.  change the first argument value from 0 to 255 to achieve the transculency you desire.  Here is the Color.argb method javadoc -  [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))